# Configure Delete indices based on size index lifecycle management Policy Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Version: ES 7.6.0
I have an elastic search set up with filebeat for pulling up logs and rollover configured with index policy(ILM).
I have 2 phases configured: HOT and DELETE.
In the delete phase for index policy, there is option in kibana to delete based on the number of days from rollover which I am having as 3 days.
I recently faced an issue wherein the load test was performed and there was a sudden spike in disk usage, index policy did not delete the indices as rollover configured was 3 days. As a result, there were watermark alerts after 95 % and the index went into read-only mode.
My question is for such a scenario is there a way in index policy to delete old indices after a certain threshold of disk space is utilized instead of just configuring deletion based on a number of days from the last rollover of the index?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is no yet implemented by ES .
Below is the link for open feature request:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/49392

Comment: I would like to know the work arounds for this without using "Curator" .